# Compiler claims that method which returns a struct does not exist

Tags: c++

I created a `struct SensorRecordTuple` with two fields in C++. The first is a `long` and the second is a generic `typename T`

My class `SensorRecorder` has two methods. The first method is to save the `SensorRecordTuple` on a file and the second is to read it from the file. For reading, I have the method `read()` with no arguments which is calling the `template<typename T> SensorRecordTuple<T> read(long relativeTime)` with one argument. This is for the first line of the file which has the relative time ZERO.

```
template<typename T>
struct SensorRecordTuple {
    long time;
    T *value;

    SensorRecordTuple() {
        time = -1;
        value = 0;
    }

    SensorRecordTuple(long _time, T _value) {
        time = _time;
        value = _value;
    }
};
class SensorRecorder {
private:
    std::ofstream outFile;
    std::ifstream inFile;
    std::string fileName;
    boost::filesystem::path full_path;
    long long duration = -1;
public:
    const std::string OUTPUT_DIR = "out";
    const std::string EXTENSION = ".out";
    const char SEPARATOR = ',';

    SensorRecorder(const char *classNameType, PRIVILEGES privileges);
    ~SensorRecorder();

    template<typename T>
    int write(T value) {
        if (outFile.is_open()) {
            auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            auto now_ms = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now);
            auto time = now_ms.time_since_epoch();

            if (duration == -1) {
                duration = 0;
            } else {
                duration = time.count() - duration;
            }
            // write in the file
            outFile << duration << SEPARATOR << value << '\n';

            // evaluate duration time to the next write
            duration = time.count();

            std::cout << "value: " << value << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cerr << "error writing..." << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    template<typename T>
    SensorRecordTuple<T> read() {
        return read<T>(-1L);
    }

    template<typename T>
    SensorRecordTuple<T> read(long relativeTime) {

        SensorRecordTuple tuple = {-1, 0.0};

        if (!inFile.is_open()) {
            inFile.open(full_path.c_str());
        }
        // read from the file
        long d;
        char comma;
        double data;

        while (inFile >> d >> comma >> data) {
            std::cout << d << "," << data << " - size: " << data << std::endl;

            if (relativeTime == -1 && d == 0) {
                // First relative time

                inFile.close();

                // cast the value
                tuple.time = d;
                tuple.value = (T) data;
                return tuple;
            } else if (d > relativeTime) {
                // Next relative time

                inFile.close();

                // cast the value
                tuple.time = d;
                tuple.value = (T) data;
                return tuple;
            }
        }
        inFile.close();
        tuple.time = -1;
        tuple.value = (T) 0.0;
        return tuple;
    }
```

I created a test to write and after reading the file. The compiler says that the read method does not exist: `No matching member function for call to 'read'`. But the `write` exists. How come?

```
SensorRecorder *mySensorRecorderWriter = new SensorRecorder("SensorRecorderTest", PRIVILEGES::RW);
int ret = mySensorRecorderWriter->write(inputValues01);
ASSERT_EQ(ret, 1);

SensorRecorder *mySensorRecorderReader = new SensorRecorder(mySensorRecorderWriter->getFileName().c_str(), PRIVILEGES::RO);
SensorRecordTuple tuple01 = mySensorRecorderReader->read();
```

Comment: `return read(long (-1));`->`return read<T>(long (-1));`?

Comment: and `-1L` would be better than `long (-1)`. However `long` is not a good choice here, since it isn't guaranteed to be wider than `int`. For example on Windows, 32-bit Linux as well as most 32-bit architectures `long` has the same width as `int`

Comment: thanks. When I do `SensorRecorder *mySensorRecorderReader = new SensorRecorder(mySensorRecorderWriter->getFileName().c_str(), PRIVILEGES::RO); SensorRecordTuple tuple01 = mySensorRecorderReader->read();`, why Am I getting the error: `no matching function for call to ‘SensorRecorder::read()’`? But I am not getting the error for the line `SensorRecordTuple tuple02 = mySensorRecorderReader->read(tuple01.time);`

Comment: @FelipeOliveiraGutierrez 1) Why are you using pointers? There's no need to. 2) "_But I am not getting the error for the line_" As far as the code you shown: you would get the error for both lines. Please provide [mcve] if you see different behavior.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I edited the question with the error of the class instantiation and the pointer. I don't know how to work without pointers in this test. The code does not compile without pointers....

Comment: @FelipeOliveiraGutierrez 1) The code you posted in the question, doesn't match the snippet you posted in the comments. `T` in `int write(T value)` gets deduced by the `value` you pass in. What `T` should be deduced in `read ()` call, if you don't, explicitly, specify it? 2) "_The code does not compile without pointers_" I see no reason why it shouldn't compile without pointers. `mySensorRecorderWriter` could be declared as `SensorRecorder mySensorRecorderWriter ("SensorRecorderTest", PRIVILEGES::RW);` for example.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius ok. I got to work without pointers. Know I am going to fix the struct `SensorRecordTuple` with a generic variable.

Comment: There's also an error in the constructor of `SensorRecordTuple` where you assign a `T` to a `T*`.

Comment: How should I declare a generic type inside a `struct`? and afterward assign values to it?

Comment: @phuclv `-` actually is an operator and not part of the literal, and can have unexpected effects under some conditions. Personally I think `long(-1)` is a good way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read()` is not a function. It is a function template.

However, you did not provide any template arguments, and there are no function arguments from which to deduce the template arguments (unlike with the other `read` overload).

So your call just attempts to invoke a normal function `read`, which does not exist.

Like your compiler, I don't know what `T` you wanted, but you'll need to supply one here:

```
SensorRecordTuple tuple01 = mySensorRecorderReader->read<HERE>();
```

---

By the way, your constructor is broken. It attempts to assign a `T` to a `T*`. This can't work.

Don't be tempted to just assign `&_value`, either, as this is a local variable.

From this line later:

```
tuple.value = (T) 0.0;
```

… it does appear that you intended for `value` to be a numeric value, not a pointer. So, presuming you do not actually want to delay construction of that member, just store a value and initialise it properly:

```
template<typename T>
struct SensorRecordTuple {
    long time;
    T value;

    SensorRecordTuple()
       : time(-1)
       , value(0)
    {}

    SensorRecordTuple(long _time, T _value)
       : time(_time)
       , value(_value)
    {}
};
```

In general you'd want `, value(std::move(_value))` but, since your example `T` are all built-in numeric types (which cannot be move-constructed), and since `std::move` complicates the example, I've omitted it.